# New ui-router states are not created

Tags: angularjs

I have this code (inherited an app)

```
angular.module('somename').
config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.
        /**
         * Login Form State
         **/
        state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.tpl.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
            authenticate: false,
            bodyClass: 'login'
        }).
        /**
         * Root View, Sees Widgets States
         */
        state('logged-in', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/logged-in-root.tpl.html',
            controller: 'rootCtrl',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'home'
        }).
        /**
         * The Search Form States
         */
        state('logged-in.search', {
            url: 'search',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'search',
            pageTitle: 'Search | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'main@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/search/search.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'searchCtrl'
                }
            }
        }).

        /**
         * List of Results States
         */
        state('logged-in.results', {
            url: 'results',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'results',
            pageTitle: 'Results | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'main@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/results/results.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'resultsCtrl'
                }
            }
        }).

        /**
         * Viewing All Profiles States
         */
        // List of all profiles without specific selected
        state('logged-in.result-all', {
            url: 'result',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'result',
            pageTitle: 'Result | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'main@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/result/result.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'resultCtrl'
                }
            }
        }).
        // Adding a new profile
        state('logged-in.result-all.new-profile', {
            url: '/profile/new',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'new-profile',
            pageTitle: 'New Profile | Crowdskout',
            templateUrl: 'views/result/new-profile.tpl.html',
            controller: 'newProfileCtrl'
        }).     
        // Specific profile selected
        state('logged-in.result-all.profile', {
            url: '/profile/:profileId',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'profile',
            pageTitle: 'Profile | Crowdskout',
            templateUrl: 'views/result/profile.tpl.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        }). 

        /**
         * Viewing a Specific Result Set States
         */
        // List of all the matching profiles without a specific profile selected
        state('logged-in.result', {
            url: 'result/:resultId',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'result',
            pageTitle: 'Result | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'main@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/result/result.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'resultCtrl'
                }
            }
        }).
        // Adding a new profile while viewing a specific result set
        state('logged-in.result.new-profile', {
            url: '/profile/new',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'new-profile',
            pageTitle: 'New Profile | Crowdskout',
            templateUrl: 'views/result/new-profile.tpl.html',
            controller: 'newProfileCtrl'
        }).
        // Viewing a specific profile within a result set
        state('logged-in.result.profile', {
            url: '/profile/:profileId',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'profile',
            pageTitle: 'Profile | Crowdskout',
            templateUrl: 'views/result/profile.tpl.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        }).

        /**
         * Taking Action on a Specific Result Set
         **/
        state('logged-in.actions', {
            url: 'result/:resultId/action',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'actions',
            pageTitle: 'Take Action | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'main@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/actions/action.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'actionCtrl'
                }
            }
        }).
        // Exporting to File
        state('logged-in.actions.export', {
            url: '/export',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'actions export',
            pageTitle: 'Export List | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'modal@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/actions/export.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'exportCtrl'
                }
            }
        }).
        // Email list
        state('logged-in.actions.email', {
            url: '/email',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'actions email',
            pageTitle: 'Email List | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'modal@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/actions/email.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'emailCtrl'
                }
            }
        }).

        /**
         * States for viewing and managing user accounts
         **/
        // View all accounts
        state('logged-in.accounts', {
            url: 'accounts',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'accounts',
            pageTitle: 'Accounts | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'main@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/account/accounts.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'accountsCtrl'
                }
            }
        }).

        // Create new account
        state('logged-in.new-account', {
            url: 'account/new',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'new-account',
            pageTitle: 'New Account | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'main@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/account/new-account.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'newAccountCtrl'
                }
            }
        }).

        // View a specific account
        state('logged-in.account', {
            url: 'account/:accountId',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'account',
            pageTitle: 'Account | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'main@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/account/account.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'accountCtrl'
                }
            }
        }).

        /**
         * States for viewing and managing outside connections
         **/
        state('logged-in.connect', {
            url: 'connect',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'connect',
            pageTitle: 'Connect | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'main@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/connect/index.tpl.html'
                }
            }
        }).

        // View and update Mailchimp accounts
        state('logged-in.connect.mailchimp', {
            url: '/mailchimp',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass: 'connect mailchimp',
            pageTitle: 'Mailchimp | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'main@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/connect/mailchimp.tpl.html'
                }
            }
        }).
        state('logged-in.connect.import', {
            url: '/import',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass : 'connect import',
            pageTitle: 'Import List | Crowdskout',
            views: {
                'main@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl: 'views/connect/import.tpl.html'
                }
            }
        }).
        state('logged-in.client', {
            url: '/client',
            authenticate: true,
            bodyClass : 'client',
            views: {
                'main@logged-in' : {
                    templateUrl:'views/client/index.tpl.html'
                }
            }

        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

The last url client isn't coming up. It redirects to login.
Thanks

Comment: Is it because of the / in the url? try changing 'url: '/client' to url: 'client'

Comment: @officert its working thanks. You can give answer to that. I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to url property of the last route to get rid of the extra slash.

```
state('logged-in.client', {
        url: 'client',
        authenticate: true,
        bodyClass : 'client',
        views: {
            'main@logged-in' : {
                templateUrl:'views/client/index.tpl.html'
            }
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try an url like baseUrl/asdfasd it will take you to /login and that is written here:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

Take a look if your link is

```
ui-sref="logged-in.client"
```

Also try in 'client' instead of '/client'

We can't tell anything else without more code.